# Is there any (legal) work-around to the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission for android?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-audiorecord

I'd like to make an app that does exactly that, but the permission is not for use by third parties. I think this would be a very useful feature.

Comment: Not for use by 3rd parties isn't a legal restriction.  In fact Android is open source, so there can be no legal restrictions on using its APIs.  It means that its a secure permission and requires your app to be a secure system app.  It won't work for a google play app, but you can root your phone and install any app you want as one.  You an find instructions on how with a quick google search